# What is Windows' equivalent of the "which" command in Unix? Is there an equivalent PowerShell command?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, which

In Linux, we have the "which" command to find out the path of an executable.
What is its Windows equivalent? Is there any PowerShell command for doing that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Comment: [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/304319/995714)

Answer (score 147):

Newer versions of Windows (I think Windows 2003 and up) have the where command:

```
C:\>where ping
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE
```

And for PowerShell, explicitly add the .exe suffix:

```
PS C:\>where.exe ping
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE
```

Comment: `where` work for me in Windows 7

Comment: This only works in cmd, not in PowerShell (in my experience)

Comment: `where /r c:\ fileName` adding the /r c:\ allowed me to perform a  recursive search starting at the root of the C drive using Windows 7 Professional it seems to not be in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/ap-doslinux.html

Comment: in Powershell you should say `where.exe ping` because `where` is by default aliased to `Where-Object` cmdlet which is completely different story

Comment: `where.exe` explicitly rather than `where` works for me in PowerShell

Comment: Does not work in Windows 10 cmd.exe

Comment: NGL, I like this name better than `which`. PS: This *worked* for me in Windows 10 cmd.exe. I typed `where.exe wsl`

Comment: That is not the equivalent of which command.  that is the equivalent of whereis command in linux. so it wont tell you which command is the executable. it just shows you all matching executables of that name in the path.

Answer (score 62):

Yes, `Get-Command` will find all commands including executables:

```
PS\> Get-Command ipconfig
```

If you want to limit the commands to just executables:

```
PS\> Get-Command -CommandType Application
```

Will find all exes in your path.  There is an alias for interactive use:

```
PS\> gcm net* -CommandType Application
```

To get the path of an executable, you can use the `Path` property of the returned object. For example:

```
PS\> (Get-Command notepad.exe).Path
```

For more info, run `man Get-Command -full`.

Answer (score 10):

`where.exe` explicitly rather than `where` works for me in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\birdc> where ping
PS C:\Users\birdc> where.exe ping
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE
```

Comment: Works on Windows 10 1903.

Comment: In PowerShell? I'm on Windows 10 Pro 1903, and `where ping` gives me nothing in PowerShell.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I meant `where.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

**Cmd**

where

```
C:\Users\X>where ping
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE

C:\Users\X>
```

**Powershell**

Get-Command

```
PS C:\Users\X> Get-Command ping
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     PING.EXE                                           10.0.1776… C:\WINDOWS\system32\PING.EXE

PS C:\Users\X>
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to user10404, the help command will work on aliases, so you can use the same command name (gcm) for help and interactive use:

```
help gcm -Parameter *
# or
man gcm -Par *
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make it short, create a one line which.cmd file with the content

```
echo %~$PATH:1
```

This will search the first parameter (%1) fed to the script and display the full path of found file.
Good place to put this script in windows 10 is
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\which.cmd

And you get your which command in path.

```
c:\>which cmd.exe

c:\>echo C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```