# Which versions/configurations of Microsoft Windows include the "where" command?

Tags: windows, shell

This question came up in the context of answering [a programming question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818545/finding-the-path-of-installed-program-from-matlab/5821788).

`where` is a handy command to locate a file on the path, roughly equivalent to the Unix `which`. My Microsoft Windows installation includes the `where` command, but it is Windows 7 with many developer tools installed. There's some information [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows/304447#304447) and [on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/207707/what-is-windows-equivalent-of-which-command-in-linux-is-there-is-equivalent-p/207709#207709) about which version/configurations of Windows include this command. Does anyone know for sure? Can you find a reference? I wasn't able to dig this out of the microsoft.com documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The official A-Z command-line reference list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390.aspx) includes the ["where" command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753148.aspx), among other things.

According to the list, it applies to Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, and Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

`where` has been included in Windows since Windows Server 2003.

Prior to that you could obtain it from the [Windows Resource Kits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Kit).

Answer (score 0):

There is not the equivalent of "which" in any version of Windows.

There are third-party tools that can add the function, however.

Edit: I was wrong. This is not true.