# Windows equivalent of which command in linux

Tags: windows

Can you please tell me what is Windows XP equivalent of “which” command in Linux?
I have tired 'where', but it does not work on Windows XP.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/207707/what-is-windows-equivalent-of-the-which-command-in-unix-is-there-an-equivale

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in Windows, but you can try one of these two substitutes:

http://nedbatchelder.com/code/utilities/wh_py.html (Click on "Download: wh.py")

or this guy created a script too:

http://pankaj-k.net/weblog/2004/11/equivalent_of_which_in_windows.html

Comment: I just found this, which also had another answer, not accepted, but with a +50 score: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities that you can choose from:

- **Use a true POSIX `which` command.** The [SFUA utility toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F), whose tools run in the [Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772343.aspx) that comes right there in the box with Windows 7 Ultimate edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 (For Windows XP, one can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778) and install [Services for UNIX version 3.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb496506.aspx).), has a `which` command, along with some 300 other POSIX tools.  [Its Korn shell also has the `type` built-in command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc978198.aspx), which of course understands the shell's own aliases.

  It comes in both x86-64 and IA64 flavours as well as x86-32.  The programs run in Windows' native proper POSIX environment, rather than with emulator DLLs (such as `cygwin1.dll`) layering things over Win32.
- **Use a Win32 port of `which`.** Oft-mentioned are [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), [cygwin](http://cygwin.com./), and [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).
- **Use a replacement command interpreter and use its built-in facilities.** [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tcmdledes.htm) is one such.  It has [a built in `WHICH` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/which.htm), which understands TCC's aliases and executable extensions.

Answer (score 0):

A bit overkill, but for completeness: [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) will give you `which` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually answered on SE, in great detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows

Maybe it should be merged to Superuser, instead marked off topic on that site.